# how can i add two columns programatically to my datagridview after binding the datagrid view in c#

Tags: c#

```
            var col3 = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            var col4 = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();

        col3.HeaderText = "Total Number";
        col3.Name = "Column3";

        col4.HeaderText = "Total Amount";
        col4.Name = "Column4";

        dataGridView1.Columns.AddRange(new DataGridViewColumn[] { col3, col4 });
```

I want to get the two columns in the left end of the datagrid,ie,after my binded data.Now I am getting the new columns in the right end.How can i do this?

Comment: If your binding datatable,you need to manipulate in datatable and then bind datatable to gridview,if your doing in winfoms you can manipulate in datagridview_cellvalidating()

Answer (score 1):

```
dataGridView1.Columns.Insert(0, col4 );
dataGridView1.Columns.Insert(0, col3);
```

Answer (score 1):

DisplayIndex property  will help you to set the order of columns .

the following link may help you

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.displayindex.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Or after adding columns to datagrid view you can use SetOrdinal(index) method to set its location.

```
    DataColumn objDc = new DataColumn("Total Amount");
    dataGridView1.Columns.Add(objDc);
    objDc.SetOrdinal(1);
```

Comment: I tried,but still i am getting the columns first.I want to get the two columns last after getting my binded datagrid view

Comment: have yoy tried something like this:objDc1.SetOrdinal(2);objDc2.SetOrdinal(3);

Comment: Refer this to chage visual location of columns:  [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.displayindex.aspx)